# Why System.Drawing.PointF is not listed at Properties.Settings types designer?

Tags: c#, application-settings

I'm not able to find the type System.Drawing.PointF at the browse option at the type of the Properties Settings.settings. Why it is not listed there?

How to reproduce:
Go to yours Projects Properties folder and click at Settings.settigs. At the type, select Browse, navigate to System.Drawing \ System.Drawing. You can see that there will be no PointF listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be the fact `PointF` does not have a `TypeConverterAttribute` but `Point` does. The way the settings provider works it needs a way to convert a string in to a object so the `DefaultSettingValueAttribute` can set the default value.

A workaround I have used in the past is break apart the class and dynamically construct it. In your settings file create two float settings called `MyPointFX` and `MyPointFY`. then click "View Code" at the top of the settings page, in the new file add the following code

```
public PointF MyPointF
{
    get
    {
        return new PointF(MyPointFX, MyPointFY);
    }
    set 
    { 
        MyPointFX = value.X;
        MyPointFY = value.Y;
    }
}
```

You will then be able to access `MyPointF` and behind the scences it will read and write the settings to the two variables `MyPointFX` and `MyPointFY`.

Comment: Nice workaround. I'm using your solution but instead of two float I'm using a SizeF. The drawback is that MyPointFX is accessible too. Thanks!

Comment: You can make it non accessable by putting the MyPointFX in the class file too and making it private, however it will not automatically generate the XML for you in the `app.config` file if you do that and you will need to add it by hand. Me personally, I just keep it in the designer and live with the extra fields.

Comment: Yeah, I can leave with that too! :)